# How should I build a multi-language help center?

Tags: java, web, playframework, multilingual

I’d like to build a help center for my app like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/help

But in addition, I want it to be multi-language so I wonder if there is a way to iterate and search over a language file like messages.en-US, messages.fr-FR, etc.? If yes, how? If no, how should I proceed to do what I want?

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/

Comment: Play Framework has its own i18n system https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaI18N. But building a dynamic help center with a search engine can be really tricky.